# RGB to HIS giving NaN for certain RGB values

Tags: c, nan

I have a function that calculates hue for a given rgb value. For some values, the `acos` returns NaN because the argument is slightly larger than 1. This code follows most of the formulas I found online but I can't figure out why NaN is popping up.

Examples are

```
40 28 28
40 28 28
40 28 28
49 25 25
46 34 34
40 28 28
42 24 24
42 24 24
40 22 22
40 22 22
```

```
#include <math.h>

double hue(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
  double rn = (double) r / (r + g + b);
  double gn = (double) g / (r + g + b);
  double bn = (double) b / (r + g + b);

  if (rn == gn && gn == bn) {
    return 0;
  }

  double h = acos((rn - gn + rn - bn) / (2.0 * sqrt((rn - gn) * (rn - gn) + (rn - bn) * (gn - bn))));

  // issue with the argument of acos being just slightly bigger than 1. Approximate to 0
  if (isnan(h)) {
    h = 0;
  }

  if (b > g) {
    return (2 * M_PI - h) * (180.0 / M_PI);
  } else {
    return h * (180.0 / M_PI);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out why NaN is popping up

And the answer is there in your question:

> because the argument is slightly larger than 1

---

The correct question would be in this case:

> How should I make sure that the argument to `acos` is not bigger than 1?

For that, you need to analyze your formula and see where the problem comes from. It is possible that the `sqrt` and the division play a role.

The easiest hack (might be bad for your application) is to verify first if the argument is bigger than 1, and if yes, truncate it to 1.

---

Please notice that you loose extra precision calculating `rn`, `gn`, `bn`. The argument to `sqrt` might better be calculated as:

```
a = (r-g)*(r-g)+(r-b)*(g-b);
b = (r+g+b)*(r+g+b);
argument = a/b;
```

Play with it and see what happens.

---

Also, the sequence

```
// issue with the argument of acos being just slightly bigger than 1. Approximate to 0
if (isnan(h)) {
    h = 0;
}
```

should be used before calling `acos`, and using the (precalculaed) argument of `acos` instead of the calculated `h`.

Comment: Ended up truncating the argument to 1. I don't think there's a way to fix the floating point stuff.

Comment: "Fixing" might not be possible, but improving the results by minimizing errors is (sometimes) possible.